# An error is reported if newFixedThreadPool does not return a value

Tags: java, intellij-idea, executorservice

```
public class MyThreadPool {
    ExecutorService es= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(6);
    Executors.newFixedThreadPool(6);
}
```

If you enter the code like this in IDEA.At line3 will be error:Cannot resolve symbol 'newFixedThreadPool'.Why would I write code like that?Because normally I would write  `A.Method1().var` .When IDEA sees `.var` will automatically complement the return value.But not in this case. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

In Java, no statements except variables declarations/initialization may take place outside of methods or initialization blocks.

```
ExecutorService es= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(6);
```

This is a declaration. It is valid to assign it a value.

```
Executors.newFixedThreadPool(6);
```

This is not a declaration. So it is not a valid statement to be outside a method or initialization block.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe I'd rather know why `.var` is not autocomplete in IDEA on this case.

Comment: @David_Guan sorry, I didn't understand that your question is specifically about IntelliJ IDEA variable extraction feature. From what I've seen, may be the second statement doesn't work because IDEA doesn't want to infer the variable name - this is just my guess. Let's see if someone who knows IDEA better is able to answer.